# Matrix in C: is that functions share local variables?

Tags: c, variables, matrix, global-variables

I defined as a global variable in `int main()` a matrix `a[][]`, i didn't initialised the variable.

Then I used some function:

- The first one: receives as argument the matrix `a` and then defines `a[i][j]` as a certain value (random), this for all i and j in the appropriate range. The function simply returns 1;
- The second one: receives as argument the matrix `a` and simply prints it. Also this function simply returns 1;
- The last one: receives as argument the matrix `a` and then determines the maximum of its values and return that values

I thought, naively, that writing plainly the code without defining some pointer to the matrix, to make the variable of the matrix global and sharable from all the functions, the code simply wouldn't have worked. But it worked.
I thought that it wouldn't have worked because i didn't defined the matrix in a global way, but it is defined *only* in a function and then (to me:)pretends to pass to the other functions.

So my question is: why it worked?

The code:

```
int matrix_definition(int a[][], int dim);
int matrix_print(int a[][], int dim);
int max_matrix(int a[][],int dim);

int main()
{
  int a[][], dim;

  matrix_definition(a,dim);
  matrix_print(a,dim);

  printf("%d", max_matrix(a,dim));
  return 0;
}
```

The full code including main() and  matrix_definition is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100


    int matrix_definition(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int dim);
    int matrix_print(int a[SIZE][SIZE], int dim);
    int max_matrix(int a[SIZE][SIZE],int dim);

    int main()
    {
      int a[SIZE][SIZE], dim;

      matrix_definition(a,dim);
      matrix_print(a,dim);

      printf("%d", max_matrix(a,dim));
      return 0;
    }

int matrix_definition(int a[SIZE][SIZE],int dim)
{
 int i,j;
srand(time(NULL));

for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
            {
                a[i][j]=rand()%2;
            }
    }
return 1;
    }
```

Comment: welcome to undefined behaviour; if you could write to an undefined memory zone without crashing the machine, you probably can read it back...

Comment: This code shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: 'I defined as a global variable in int main()' no, you didn't.

Comment: Yes, this code should not compile.  It does not compile on my system nor would I expect it to.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm using code blocks

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE, but is not itself a compiler.  It can use many different compilers.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Ooops, I'm sorry. I checked for the compiler: is the GNU GCC compiler

Comment: @HaroldF    Not compile for sure - Please compile first ...

Comment: Well GCC is definitely not compiling it on my system, even ignoring that you did not include all of the functions in your code.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons : I tried and it always compiles, i will edit my answer now and i will write the code for the first function and the exact part i wrote in the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated code you posted is **very** different from what you originally posted.   Yes, that code is valid with regard to how `a` is defined and how it is passed to various functions.

In each of your function declarations you declare a parameter:

```
int a[SIZE][SIZE]
```

Since arrays as parameters are converted to pointers, this is equivalent to:

```
int (*a)[SIZE]
```

This is compatible with the variable defined in `main`:

```
int a[SIZE][SIZE];
```

When passing an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element.  So this function call:

```
matrix_definition(a,dim);
```

is the same as:

```
matrix_definition(&a[0],dim);
```

The expression `a[0]` has type `int [SIZE]`, so the expression `&a[0]` has type `int (*)[SIZE]`.  This is the same as the function's parameter.